# Как корректно написать запрос с UNION?

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как правильно должен быть написан запрос к БД с UNION?

В таблице существуют поля fo, subekt, polisk, fond, abc1, c2. Поле fond имеет значния только распределенный и нераспределенный.
Необходимо написать запрос к этой таблице таким образом, чтобы результат вместо этого набора выводил данные в виде: fo, subekt, polisk, fond, abc1_rasp, c2_rasp, abc1_nerasp, c2_rasp.

Иначе говоря, вместо 
[image: Первый вариант]

должен быть второй: [image: Второй варинт]

Есть запрос

```
select fo, region, polisk, abc1 as abc1_rasp, c2 as c2_rasp, null as abc1_nerasp, null as c2_nerasp
from v_report_zap
where fond like  'распред%'
union  
select fo, region, polisk, abc1 as abc1_nerasp, c2 as c2_nerasp, null as abc1_rasp, null as c2_rasp
from v_report_zap
where fond like  'нераспред%'
```

Но срабатывает в нем только первая часть. То есть, в запасах нераспределенного фонда всегда остаются NULL'ы. Хотя каждый из них работает по отдельности правильно.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

`union` объединяет результаты двух подзапросов опираясь на порядок колонок, а не на их название. Поэтому в Вашем случае `abs1_nerasp` и `c2_nerasp` всегда `null`. Названия колонок в нижнем подзапросе вообще не важны.

В вашем случае запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
select fo, region, polisk, abc1 as abc1_rasp, c2 as c2_rasp, null as abc1_nerasp, null as c2_nerasp from v_report_zap where fond like  'распред%'
union  
select fo, region, polisk, null as abc1_rasp, null as c2_rasp, abc1 as abc1_nerasp, c2 as c2_nerasp from v_report_zap where fond like  'нераспред%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select fo, fond, 
       if(fond='Y', abc, null) abc_rasp, 
       if(fond='Y', c2, null) c2_rasp, 
       if(fond='N', abc, null) abc_nerasp, 
       if(fond='N', c2, null) c2_nerasp 
   from t1
```

результат

```
|     fo | fond | abc_rasp | c2_rasp | abc_nerasp | c2_nerasp |
|--------|------|----------|---------|------------|-----------|
|  Центр |    N |   (null) |  (null) |     (null) |         3 |
|     ДВ |    Y |        5 |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
|     ДВ |    Y |       12 |       6 |     (null) |    (null) |
| Сибирь |    Y |        7 |      10 |     (null) |    (null) |
```

[**demo на sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91055/2)